# How to import a self-made module in Docker?

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to run a Docker project that has 3 containers.

Whenever I run

`$ docker-compose up --build`

the whole process goes well with no warnings or errors on the screen.

The problem is that the tasks the containers should do are not carried out. When I check for the log file, it has the following content:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/etl_script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from logs.log import log, database_error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logs.log'
```

The main components on my directory structure are as follows:

```
.
+-- crontab
+-- deploy.yml
+-- docker-compose.yml
+-- Dockerfile
+-- elt_script.py
+-- README.md
+-- requirements.txt
+-- logs
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- log.py
```

When the *etl_script.py* is executed, the error I previously mentioned is written in the log file. The line at the *etl_script.py* that generates the error message is:

```
from logs.log import log, database_error
```

and the content of logs.log.py is:

```
from datetime import datetime

def database_error(error):
    log(error)

def log(message):
    print("[%s] %s" % (datetime.now(), message))
```

Could anyone help me finding out what I am doing wrong? I'm pretty new to Docker.

EDIT 1:

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk12:x86_64-alpine-jre-12.33

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3.6 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
rm -r /root/.cache

ENV ENV=${ENV}

WORKDIR /code

ADD requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD cogroo4py /code/cogroo4py
RUN python /code/cogroo4py/setup.py install

ENV APP_USER appuser

RUN adduser -g "App User" -D $APP_USER

COPY crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$APP_USER
RUN chmod 0777 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$APP_USER

ADD . /code

RUN touch /code/cron.log

RUN chmod 0777 /code/cron.log

RUN chmod 0777 /code/

RUN chmod 0777 /etc/crontabs/$APP_USER

CMD ["crond", "-f", "-d", "0"]
```

Comment: Your stack traces don't match your directory structure. Note that the path of `etl_script` is `/code/etl_script.py`. Does `logs` exist inside `/code` as well?

Comment: Can you include your image's `Dockerfile` in the question too; it will be essential to understanding what's going on here?  How are you launching the container (and are you using `volumes:` to hide the code in the image)?

Comment: I have added the Dockerfile. It actually creates a *code* folder and defines it as the workdir.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to add `ENV PYTHONPATH /path/to/my/code` to the Dockerfile.